# IBM Bluemix Alchemy API key invalid

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I'm trying to run keyword extraction from Alchemy API and I don't understand why my API key is not valid. To be clear, I have read both these two answers on SO:

1. [Where do I specify the AlchemyAPI key in Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36882961/3199478)
2. [Where to get the Alchemyapi API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37438315/3199478)

Even though I registered via Bluemix, I have also tried to check if my key is valid by using this URL:

> http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/info/GetAPIKeyInfo?apikey=my_api_key_here

Nothing.

Lastly, I have waited over 10 hours for the key to become validated and still nothing.

**How do I get a valid API key???**

I have tested my key with these two repos:

1. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

   - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/alchemy_language_v1.py
2. https://github.com/alchemyapi/alchemyapi_python

Additional Info:
When viewing my credentials for the service in Bluemix, I get the following:

```
{
  "credentials": {
  "url": "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls",
  "note": "It may take up to 5 minutes for this key to become active.",
  "apikey": "**********"
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the `BASE_URL` for the `ENDPOINT` in the Python SDK of Alchemy API and got the following error:

> hostname 'gateway-a.watsonplatform.net' doesn't match either of 'access.alchemyapi.com', 'www.access.alchemyapi.com'
>   Error in combined call:  network-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seems like the problem was server-side and has been resolved now. It affected quite a lot of users, not just me.